# Async method in abstract class

Tags: java, spring-boot, abstract

I'd like to have an `@Async` method inside an abstract class, but it seems not to work (if i put some logs, it's the same thread).

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    ...

    @Async
    public final void someAsyncTask() {
        ...
    }

    public abstract void doMyStuff();
}
```

```
@Service
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    ...

    @Override
    public void doMyStuff() {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class Initializer {

    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // This call is NOT async
        myClass.someAsyncTask();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ...
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
}
```

If the `@Async` method is directly inside MyClass (which no longer extends MyAbstractClass as it's now useless) : it works !

Any advise on why `@Async` seems not to works in abstract class ?

I'm using SpringBoot 2.1.3.RELEASE

Comment: The above code works for me, can you print the thread name in Async method

Comment: how are you testing `Async` execution? by printing thread name?

Comment: By printing Thread Name + Id. thread name = main; id = 1. When it works, it print ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-XXX

Comment: for me it is always printing the Async thread name

Comment: Do you use the exact same Spring version ? (i'm trying to reproduce this in a brand new project)

Comment: it is working for me on `2.1.3` and `2.1.5`

Comment: @Deadpool.... i found it ... my '@Async' method was 'final' ... and... it changes everything ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was all because `someAsyncTask` was `final`.

It was final to prevent this method from beeing `@Override`.

It seems not possible to do so and keep `@Async`.

Thanks @Deadpool for your help !